# More than one action on html from?

Tags: php, html, forms, web, paypal

I have a paypal button on webpage that adds item to shopping basket.
Can I add another action to the paypal form so that it will send me an email confirmation as well as do the orginal task of 'adding to basket'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitTwice(f){
f.action = 'first.php';
f.target='ifr1';
f.submit();
f.action = 'second.php';
f.target='ifr2';
f.submit();
}
</script>
```

and the form:

```
<form method="post">

<input type="button" value="Send" onsubmit="submitTwice(this.form)">
</form>
```

Comment: You are submitting it to an original page also, after all

Comment: and if you submit your form with `enter`, your callback is not applied. Better to use `submit` event of form.

Comment: javascript solution like this would be insecure - nothing stops a hacker from manually calling one without the other. maybe okay in another context, but not payments.

Comment: @Spudley I agree. An action should be taken server-side.